# Issues with parallax site using skrollr, skrollr-menu in iOS7

Tags: javascript, plugins, ios7, skrollr

i'm using skrollr.js and skrollr-menu for creating a parallax website. I have 3 divs with nested elements that i would like to parallax at different speed. Everything works as expected on desktop but on iPad running iOS 7 i am experiencing a problem with the way the elements are positioned and the speed at which they scroll. The 3 different divs have a class of position: fixed, and nested elements a class of position: absolute; and are positioned on Y axis using top:px, (tried using % instead with mixed results). other (non-nested, ie. #content) divs seem to be working consistently across all browsers and device though. I would really appreciate any help with this problem it has been driving me crazy for days, this is my first project using skrollr so i dont have much expericence but so far i'm loving it except for this glitch on iOS, i have checked the documentation and related question in stackOverflow but still no luck! Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction, here's a fiddle of how im trying to achieve this, although to see it in iOS i will have to provide a direct link to the project shortly, please bear with me since i had to port an existing project for using it with skrollr on mobile devices so i would like to clean up code as much as possible before submitting to avoid confusion, in the meantime here is the fiddle:

```
//Init Skrollr
```

$(document).ready(function(){
        var s = skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: false,
            smoothScrolling: true,
            smoothScrollingDuration: 150
        });

```
    skrollr.menu.init(s, {
        easing: 'outCubic',
        animate: true,
        duration: 1000
```

});
});

http://jsfiddle.net/shinobisan/EvPdL/6/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile the `skrollr-body` element is moved using CSS transforms, which will break fixed positioned elements. Please read this part of the documentation, which I just extended with a second paragraph.

> Starting with skrollr 0.6.0 there's just one thing you need to do: Include an element on your page with the id skrollr-body. That's the element we move in order to fake scrolling. The only case were you don't need a #skrollr-body is when using position:fixed exlusively. In fact the skrollr website doesn't include a #skrollr-body element. If you need both fixed and non-fixed (i.e. static) elements, put the static ones inside the #skrollr-body element.
>
> Or to put it differently: On mobile the skrollr-body element is moved using CSS transforms. You can't have position:fixed or background-attachment:fixed inside elements which use CSS transforms as per CSS spec (http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/). That's why those elements need to be outside of the skrollr-body element.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#what-you-need-in-order-to-support-mobile-browsers

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! i think i'm beginning to understand how skroll-body works only this issue with iOS has me totally confused! I have modified the fiddle as you suggested by placing the parallax element outside of skroll-body, but no luck, this time it works on my screen but on iPad it is sent way off to the bottom barely visible in portrait mode and not shown in landscape. I have added a target div contained within content div in the to visualize the problem, were #non-nested-img should line up with target's position both on screen and on device (section2).

Comment: It would be best to provide you with a live example only my server is down at the moment, hopefully the fiddle will help us get the point across for now. Thanks again for taking the time to look into my problem! http://jsfiddle.net/shinobisan/EvPdL/8/

Comment: Sorry, in your fiddle I don't see any animations, just scrolling.

Comment: Update: after much testing i finally went back to original project and applied the same principles. Now the site scrolls on iPad only with minor glitches! i put the static elements inside skrollr-body and left all fixed, absolute positioned elements out as you suggested, skrollr needs to make that distinction in order to properly scroll to an element, the problem was that content was pushed to bottom of page and menu was trying to reach content but couldn't get there.

Comment: The glitch i'm getting now is when changing from portrait to landscape mode on iPad skrollr-menu gets a little crazy, but when i reload the page in landscape mode everything is ok, this doesn't seem to happen from landscape to portrait(i can only test in iOS7 atm.). In order to rule out css i am currently cleaning up my code, also worth noting i am using s.refresh() in live example when calling skrollr.init(), although commenting this line changes nothing.

Comment: Fiddle wasn't working because my server is still down and skroll-menu.js was not loading, so i added external link to your repository and updated it here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/shinobisan/EvPdL/9/) for demonstration purposes only, but for debugging i was wondering if it is possible to pm you the link of production server so you can see live example, i just don't feel comfortable disclosing this information in public since my client might not like this, if that's ok with you of course! will report back soon if anything else comes up!

Comment: You can send it to alexander@prinzhorn.it , I don't have an iPad though.

Comment: i sent you an email hopefully you can take a look! Will follow shortly with some screenshots of iPad so you can see problem i'm having, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much @Prinzhorn for his kind support and feedback, unfortunately i was unable to fully debug problem since i no longer have the device for testing, but will update answer with all pointers and tips provided by Prinzhorn, as well as a proper example of the problem so that other users can benefit from this answer.